# Django : How to filter users with username__iexact by default?

Tags: python, django, orm

Implementing username case-insensitive :

I want to implicitly imply `iexact` when querying for `user` :

```
user = User.objects.get(username = 'yugal')  # Lowercase
user.id # 1

user = User.objects.get(username = 'YUgal')  # Mixcase
user.id # 1
```

How can I achieve this ? { somehow with `UserManager` }

**Note:**

- Also, `django.shortcuts.get_object_or_404` seems to use it as `User.objects.get_query_set().all().get()`. How can we make it work ?

Comment: btw: wouldn't be generally better to have all usernames in DB stored in lowercase and query them as `User.objects.get(username='YuGal'.lower()) ?

Comment: The thing is : `.lower()` is a solution for my code. But will not work with 3rd party apps. Since they might use it without `.lower()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I figured out a way to implement it for all db queries :

```
###### QuerySet #######
def _filter_or_exclude(self, negate, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'username' in kwargs:
        kwargs['username__iexact'] = kwargs['username']
        del kwargs['username']
    if args or kwargs:
        assert self.query.can_filter(),\
        "Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken."
    from django.db.models import Q
    clone = self._clone()
    if negate:
        clone.query.add_q(~Q(*args, **kwargs))
    else:
        clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
    return clone

from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
QuerySet._filter_or_exclude = _filter_or_exclude
######################
```

This solved the problem.

Comment: The solution may be objectionable to some, but to achieve the desired result - This is the only possible solution with minimum side effects. If someone has a better solution - Feel free to add an answer. Remember, it must support 3rd party apps out of the box.

Answer (score 4):

explicit:

```
user = User.objects.get(username__iexact='yugal')
```

implicit: override `User` model let you can override `objects` property, where you add custom `iexact` handling:

```
class MyUser(User):

    class Meta:
        proxy = True


    objects = MyManager()


class MyManager(UserManager):

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):

       if 'username' in kwargs:
           kwargs['username__iexact'] = kwargs['username']
           del kwargs['username']
       return super(MyManager, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: All seem to work, but its not working with `django.shortcuts.get_object_or_404`. Can we make that work to assume `iexact` for username ?

Comment: @YugalJindle can you show code how do you use `get_object_or_404`?

Comment: Just like any one else does : `user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)`

Comment: should be `get_object_or_404(MyUser, username=username)`

Comment: For that I will have to refactor all my code to use the proxy User model. Plus I can't do that with 3rd party apps.